# Migrating SASS codebase to PostCSS

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css, postcss

I had a plain CSS file that would apply a theme to my Nuxt 3 project, but I chose to convert to SASS so that I can make use of variables and nesting so that future changes (such as theme colors, etc) can be made easily. In addition, I wanted to integrate this with TailwindCSS until I realised that [PostCSS is the way to go](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#using-sass-less-or-stylus) for that.

I've spent many hours of turning that plain CSS into multi-file SASS and now I'm desperate of converting that into PostCSS so that I can make use of Tailwind directives and functions in all files which would then be fed into the Nuxt 3 project.

Is there any way I can do this migration easily and preferably keeping the nesting and variables still there (possibly the ability to half-compile SASS)?

Comment: You should be able to do nesting, in the same manner as with SASS, for a starter see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting. There are also postcss plugins for Sass-like variables, https://github.com/csstools/postcss-advanced-variables

Comment: Thank you, and I do intend on using those plugins for PostCSS. However, I still have hurdles of mixins, conditionals, etc. I can search for plugins for those as well but they seem to be inactive and also add lot more to the dependencies whereas I'm hoping that I can find a middle ground by compiling those parts to CSS without affecting the nesting and variables.

Comment: You should be able to use PostCSS plugins to parse the css code to get it into a state that you want. Example, find a PostCSS plugin that processes the mixins, just run that once to update your code. Then you have your css in a state that no longer has mixins. Do that for all the things you want to remove from Sass to get your css into a starting state that you want. Then commit that code. That sounds like the middle ground you are looking for,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of configuring PostCSS heavily by installing and configuring multiple plugins, I was able to make use of Tailwind using [`tailwindcss/nesting`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting) (to keep the ability to have nested styles) and [`theme()`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme) utilities they provide (for variables, therefore also configuring [`theme`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme) option in `tailwind.config.js`).